# Install Omnibus Gitlab on subdomain

Tags: git, apache, centos, subdomain, gitlab

I'm trying to install GitLab on an existing server that's running CentOS 6.5 and Apache as the web server. The gitlab service should be accessible through a sub-domain. I'm using the Omnibus installation package. After installation I create the gitlab.rb configuration file:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/gitlab
sudo touch /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
sudo chmod 600 /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

and add:

```
external_url "http://gitlab.the_domain.com"
```

for the sub-domain url. After restarting and reconfiguring GitLab, when I go on "domain.com" it shows the GitLab login page and not the website that should be shown.

Is there a way to fix this and use GitLab on the sub-domain, and the main site on the domain using the Omnibus installation package?

Comment: have you fix that,.?
i have the same requirement here,.

Comment: @simaremare no, not yet. I found some posts that suggested to configure mod_proxy on apache or something similar on nginx but The server I'm trying to configure it on has several other sites and I can't experiment on it.

Answer (score 1):

`external_url` is used for the links shown in project urls, the sub-domain would be configured by nginx/apache

Comment: I checked that. The external_url value is reconfigured into nginx as well. It also configures the port number in nginx if I add it.